# Cups : Interface script for virtual printer not executing commands

Tags: shell-script, cups, printer

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Interface script running" >> /home/user/printer.log
cat "$6"
```

My printer :

```
lpadmin -p testprint -i script.sh -v file:/dev/null -E
```

It goes into the script and works but it doesn't create the file `printer.log`. I tried various commands beside `echo` ( start another script, launch `gedit` in background ) and it looks like it doesn't execute any of the commands in the script except the `cat "$6"`. It doesn't give any error. If I comment out the `cat "$6"` it gives an error when printing so it obviously goes through the script.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your CUPS running chroot-ed?

Comment: Use `/tmp/printer.log` to start with to see if that works.  The `cups` user is unlikely to have access to `/home/user`.  If that works you then need to create a "secure" version which doesn't suffer race conditions and potential file-overwrite issues.

Comment: I didn't chroot, used default install on debian jessie. I just noticed I get a "permission denied" on `echo "Interface script running" >> /home/user/printer.log` in `/var/log/cups/error_log`. I tried `/tmp/printer.log` earlier and it doesn't work either, no files to be found. Interrestingly enough though is that there is nothing in `/var/log/cups/error_log` when using `/tmp/printer.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface scripts are run under the control of `cups` and are not run as the user doing the printing.  This means that it's not connected to your terminal or X-display; it can not open windows or write to your home directory.

If you look at `/etc/cups/cups-files.conf` (maybe different location on your OS) there are lines such as

```
# Default user and group for filters/backends/helper programs; this cannot be
# any user or group that resolves to ID 0 for security reasons...
User lp
Group lp
```

This means, in my case, the scripts are run as user `lp:lp`.

Depending on how `cups` is run (eg `systemd`) it may also run with some further layer of isolation; e.g. an "overlay" of `/tmp` which means that the files writing here are not visible outside.

However, `/var/spool/cups/tmp` may be available for writing and visible.

eg

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Interface script running $$" >> /var/spool/cups/tmp/my_log
/usr/bin/mount >> /var/spool/cups/tmp/my_log
/bin/id >> /var/spool/cups/tmp/my_log
df >> /var/spool/cups/tmp/my_log
cat "$6"
```

Now in `/var/spool/cups/tmp/my_log` we can see some results:

```
Interface script running 22462
/dev/vda3 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=499340k,nr_inodes=124835,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
....
uid=4(lp) gid=7(lp) groups=7(lp)
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda3        3041808 1380564   1487012  49% /
devtmpfs          499340       0    499340   0% /dev
tmpfs             508452       0    508452   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             508452       0    508452   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs             508452   13016    495436   3% /run
tmpfs             101692       0    101692   0% /run/user/500
/dev/vda1         487634  119954    337984  27% /boot
```

This was tested on CentOS 7; it should work on Debian as well.

Comment: Thanks just figured out the User/Group part but was stuck with putting a user and didn't want that. `/var/spool/cups/tmp/my_log` indeed works. I wanted this to work with all users and put the file in their home directory. Is there any way to run script as current user ? Should I make all users join the lp group ?

Comment: If you add people to the `lp` group then they'll have the ability to read and potentially modify files they shouldn't.  You could create a new directory (eg `/var/printjoboutput` and allow everyone to read that, and `lp` to write to it).  Then anyone can read the results.  If you want the script to run as the user who spooled the job then you can use any of the standard tools (eg `sudo`) to wrap another script that does the output.  That may be worth creating a new question.